# AND condition not working in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Please i need your help with my script. Whenever i include

```
AND maintable.semester_name = '$semester_name'
```

in the MySQL Query, it returns 0 for both values of semester_name, when actually 
only one is supposed to have a value of 0 when echo $nums is processed. When i 
remove

```
AND maintable.semester_name = '$semester_name'
```

the query gives normal results as i expect.

Thanks.

```
$query = "SELECT *             
   FROM maintable 
   WHERE maintable.matric_no = '$matric_no'
   AND   maintable.session = '$session'
   AND   maintable.semester_name = '$semester_name'
   AND   maintable.level = '$level'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$nums = mysql_numrows($result);
echo $nums ;
```

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
COURSES
  course_id int(100) 
  course_code varchar(100) 
  course_title varchar(100) 
  course_unit int(10) 

MAINTABLE
  maintable_id int(255) 
  matric_no int(10) 
  session varchar(10) 
  semester_name varchar(10) 
  course_code varchar(10) 
  level int(10) 
  score int(10) 
  grade varchar(4) 

RESULT_UPLOAD
  upload_id int(10) 
  session varchar(10) 
  semester_name  varchar(10) 
  course_code varchar(10) 
  level varchar(10) 

SEMESTER
  semester_id int(10) 
  semester_name varchar(10) 

STUDENT
  matric_no int(10) 
  first_name varchar(100) 
  last_name varchar(100) 
  other_name varchar(100) 
  level int(10) 

USERS
  users_id int(10) 
  title varchar(20) 
  first_name varchar(20) 
  last_name varchar(20) 
  username varchar(20) 
  password varchar(100) 
  register_date datetime 
  tmp_name varchar(100) 
  type varchar(20) 
  name varchar(20) 
  size int(10) 

YEAR
  level_id int(10) 
  level int(10)
```

Comment: You're aware of SQL Injections?

Comment: `the query gives normal results as i expect`, both of those examples are the same. Was that a typing mistake or does on really work and then not work?

Comment: could you check the part of the post before the "Thanks"... both the query part seem to be same...

Comment: @cillosis there's supposed to be a remove before i wrote the query. I've updated the question. I've run the query in phpmyadmin, and it returned empty. But actually i have the data inside.. I'm quite sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is correct. I guess your conditions really don't match any rows in the table. Just check what values you have in the database and what your are passing into the conditions.

Comment: I've run the query in phpmyadmin, and it returned empty. But actually i have the data inside.. I'm quite sure

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct, but with bit of ambiguity. The following query is run as exactly you are doing, but with less words.

```
$query = "SELECT *             
   FROM maintable 
   WHERE matric_no = '$matric_no'
   AND   session = '$session'
   AND   semester_name = '$semester_name'
   AND   level = '$level'";
```

Now, about your **problem**, the only way this might be happening may be due to no record is matching the records in your database.

Try to get the query you are running with `echo $query` and run the query directly from phpmyadmin to see how many result set you will get.

Comment: I've run the query in phpmyadmin, and it returned empty. But actually i have the data inside.. I'm quite sure

Comment: @dotman14, There is no other possible explanation to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query ...it works

```
$query = "SELECT *FROM maintable WHERE maintable.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'AND maintable.session = '".$session."' AND maintable.semester_name = '".$semester_name."' AND maintable.level = '".$level."' ";
```